# Is there a better way to convert json within a pandas dataframe into additional dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe arguments with the columns RecordID(Int) and additional_arguments(Json formatted string object). I am trying to convert each of the jsons into a dataframe and then concatenate them all into one dataframe. Currently, I am doing this with a for loop:

```
arguments_output = pd.DataFrame([]);
for i in range(0, len(arguments)-1):
  df = pd.DataFrame(arguments['additional_arguments'][i])
  df['RecordID'] = arguments['RecordID'][i]
  arguments_output = pd.concat([arguments_output, df])
```

This takes quite a bit of time, as there are over 55000 records total. Is there a better way to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: in python if, ```arguments``` is iterable, you don't need to range, you can just use it directly. ```for arg in arguments: foo()```

Answer (score 0):

without seeing an example input, it's hard to say, but can un-nest json.

`pandas.json_normalize()`